# Deleted EFI partition, BIOS needs long time to boot

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, windows-8, bios

So I had dual boot with Windows 8.1, and I formatted all partitions with windows, not Ubuntu. I deleted EFI (for some reason...) then BIOS showed 'disonnect all media devices and try again', I reinstalled Ubuntu.
BIOS is so laggy now, and needs 6mins to boot Ubuntu.
HELP
[partition table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Huczo.png)

EDIT: and it does make long beep sounds, then computer reboots, and only then boots. I dont think its hardware problem

Comment: Post the top few results from this: `systemd-analyze blame` Only top or major issues may show the issue. What brand/model system? Some need boot parameters to work well.

Comment: Result: https://pastebin.com/eeyqymRQ, a

Comment: and mine motherboard is gigabyte uefi

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you running?

Comment: 16.04 lts.......

Comment: Now that I think about it, it could be unrelated to the BIOS entirely. Do you have any Desktop Environment packages installed, or themes?

Comment: Yes I have some themes

Comment: its theme - numix, icon pack - numix_circle

Comment: Yeah, when I installed some themes on my computer a while back, it started booting very slowly. It may be the cause.

Comment: Or it may just be that 16.04 has boot problems and you may have to migrate to 17.04.

Comment: Mhm ill try, but I formatted EFI - i think this is problem, ill try to upgrade

Comment: and its not like slowly, but crashy, i even cant boot to setup (F12) need to wait ages

Comment: DON'T UPGRADE! reinstall and and put your files on a USB. Ubuntu has problems with upgrading.

Comment: i want to burn 17.04 to usb i cant?

Comment: Make another question for that and I might answer it

Comment: Where is 6 min to boot? Your  `systemd-analyze blame` does not show very large time for anything. I have SSD and show about half your times for most and it fully reboots - shutdown, UEFI, grub, reboot in less than 20 sec. Boot would indicate a UEFI setting issue. Do you have UEFI Secure Boot on? UEFI fast boot on (that can make it boot faster, but then you may not have time to get into UEFI to change settings).

Comment: Fixed everything by instaling fresh 17.04, the problem was in partitions i think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your BIOS is somehow damaged. In order to fix this, try `sudo grub-install`. that will install a new grub for you.

If it says "Grub is already installed" or something like that, I guess you will just have to migrate to 17.04 via USB.

NOTE: MIGRATE using a USB to store your files, and another USB to install 17.04. Ubuntu usually has trouble *upgrading*, but not *migrating*.

Comment: Got this matas@matas-H81M-D2V:~$ sudo grub-install
[sudo] password for matas: 
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
matas@matas-H81M-D2V:~$

Comment: I think that's a good sign. That's what I got

Comment: However, it may not have changed anything.

Comment: Mhm. Idk it did nothing. But look at this https://imgur.com/gallery/Kw8e7 why it has two ubuntu

Comment: did you try to boot both? And if you did, did they both go to the same partition?

Comment: With UEFI you often have two entries one for shimx64.efi and one for grubx64.efi. Shim works for secure boot and also works is secure boot is off. Grub only works if UEFI secure boot is off.